# Combine Multiple Columns in one Column MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, union, union-all

So i have multiple Columns with the same data type entry but i need to combine them into a single column.
i have 25 columns id like to list in one column in the same order

### Example:

```
D1 D2 D3 D4
15 19 16 22
```

---

```
Ds
15
19
16
22
```

Comment: ive tried lookups and a tried a couple other things. I think union would work but im not familiar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you jus want `union all`, as your tags suggest:

```
select d1 as ds from t union all
select d2 as ds from t union all
select d3 as ds from t union all
select d4 as ds from t ;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, yes I believed that would work but I was not familiar and I kept getting the wrong thing when I tried it. I will follow your format and see if it works

Comment: I tried doing this but I left out a important part. I apologize Ds is inside of another table. I trying to do this with two tables.

Comment: @NormX . . . Ask another question, with more appropriate details and sample data.  If you modify this question, you will invalidate my answer, which can draw downvotes.